# HTML button that changes display to Ajax spinner after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, input

I have a number of input button elements throughout my site that perform Ajax operations.

When a users clicks one of these buttons, I want to disable it, hide its text label, then show a centered [Ajax spinner image](http://ajaxload.info/) while it waits for either the `$.ajax()` `success` or `failure` function to fire, at which point its appearance will reset to pre-click.

I rolled my own jQuery extension to do this, but the positioning of the spinner image is slightly off in different browsers, and I don't really have the patience to debug specific browser CSS right now.

Is there a simple plugin that already provides this functionality for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you're going to have to do that yourself.  It's a CSS issue which varies a lot depending on the position of parents elements and the page itself.  Any pre-built solution would only require you to go through and change all of your html to wrap it with some standard another solution has already made.

It might be easier seeing as it's already built to simply do the cross-browser testing...